# I deployed my app to heroku, but bootstrap and angular libraries dont add

Tags: angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

https://shrouded-woodland-61669.herokuapp.com/

After deploying to heroku, the angular, and bootstrap libraries would not work on my app. This is a node express project that I cloned from git:
https://github.com/vedvasa/itinerary.git

Please advice

Comment: The GitHub link you gave is a 404 Not Found error...

Comment: @NadiaCerezo Please check now

Comment: Much better, thanks :D

Comment: Please note that angular and bootstrap are not part of the dependencies declared in the package.json... I would not expect them to work.

Comment: @NadiaCerezo do I install bootstrap and angularjs using bower or npm, or I just define the dependencies manually???
As I just cloned it from git, I did not have any bootstrap or angular dependencies added to package.json. This was originally pushed from enide studio, in which, bootstrap or angular dependencies are not required.

Comment: I would guess that if bootstrap and angular are already available in enide studio and you need them in the project, you probably need to add them in the package.json so heroku will know it has to download them.